# GDAL2Tiles and vectors

Tags: openlayers, gdal

I am trying to make an interactive map of a really big warehouse.

I have scanned blueprints and am using OpenLayers with a TMS data source (generated using GDAL2Tiles) to display the map. Everything looks fantastic, but I'm at a total loss as to how to create a vector layer on top of it!

Ideally, I'd have ~100 or so vectors on top of my warehouse, each of which would be clickable to bring up additional information, blah blah blah.. but what do i use to make the vectors, and how do i reference the same location on the image at different zoom levels, since i am not using lat/long coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do it!

Basically, doing all kinds of crazy work to make a separate vector layer in some other program is overkill - you just define vector elements using an array with their location:

See the source in this example:
[Boxes Vector](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/boxes-vector.html)

Hope this is helpful to someone!